# Intellij cannot see the path /usr/share/java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up the mysql-connector to work with intellij on my Pop OS. I know it is located on /usr/share/java but when I go in "Select Library Files" to search for it, the ide cannot find this path. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install the IDE via snaps? Try tar.gz instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: Flatpak actually. Just did it, works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snap/flatpack packaging systems are limiting IDE access to certain folders and files. It's recommended to use [the official tar.gz distribution](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) to avoid such limitations.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'd upvote your answer but I'm not allowed yet